# Is it possible to run an ionic cordova build using Java 11 instead of Java 8?

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, debian

I'm building an app using Ionic v5.2.7. When I try to run

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

I get an error

`Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.5`

I've been trying to install Java 8, but it's long since been deprecated and Debian 10 doesn't trust the public key provided by the *webupd8team* PPA. I've tried a few workarounds for installing Java 8, but if at all possible I'd much rather run this using a more modern version of Java.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** I've tried to install Java 8 using several different guides, all of which lead to a `Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate` problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer of the main question but maybe you can try to install java 8 using [jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba) (it is like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) but for java)

Comment: Thanks for that! Even jabba isn't giving me access to the oracle jdk for 1.8! (although it's the first jdk listed in the readme on the github page). It did give me access to an open jdk for 1.8 though, so hopefully that's sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but maybe the answer helps others. You can try to use sdkman to install different versions of Java and switch between them quickly.